# 3D harmonic oscillator magic numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I know that,

$$V(r) = (1/2) m \omega^2 r^2 ,$$ $$\omega \approx 40(Z+N)^{-1/3}\ \rm{MeV} $$

and $$E = (n+3/2) \hbar \omega.$$

How do you find the magic numbers of protons and neutrons which correspond to closed shells with $Z< 22$ and $N< 22$? Considering a 3D harmonic oscillator.